# Why isn't Chrome showing # in list?

Tags: html, css

I have a reset.css file that clears all lists from any types or padding. I usually don't want that. In one case I do. It's working in FF but not Chrome. If I remove `float: left` it shows the decimals. Bug or feature or what?

The markup is this:

```
<ol class="tab-group">
  <li class="tab">An Item</li>
  <li class="tab">Another Item</li>
</ol>
```

The CSS is this:

```
li.tab {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: solid 1px #CCC;
  border-left: solid 1px #CCC;
  background-color: #CCC;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  list-style-position: inside;
  display: list-item;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: If you want numbers in the list group you should use `<ol>` instead of `<ul>`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol. If that is not what you are looking for you need to be more specific with your question

Comment: It's working for me in Chrome 50 - https://jsfiddle.net/wr0h9ga5/

Comment: Updated to OL and no dice.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in Chrome 49. Updating to 50 just fixed it. What timing.

Comment: It was a *feature* in C49...they removed it in C50. :)